# MFC menu item doesn't open dialog box

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am having a proglem with the MFC application and the DialogBox. I am quiet sure I've done everything well with this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wb9s9ah.aspx
but still it doesn't work...
1. I've created new project with simple menu commands.
2. I've created new menu item (+ID) and new resource DialogBox (+ID).
3. Then I've added a new class named CParameters with the Class Wizard. For the BaseClass I've typed in CDialog.
4. I've created new handler on the menu item and added the code

```
CParameters dlg;
dlg.DoModal();
```

I think this is it, and this should work... But it doesnt... What is missing??
Here is my project, you can access it freely:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e6ajoxqk76hkuvn/AACRMY8bgcuyXguFwP240QB9a?dl=0

Additionally I want to insert TextEditors and to change parameters in my program from the dialog box.

Comment: Please include all relevant code directly into the question, but please make sure it is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most readers don't like to access off-site code. Also, please don't ask for tutorials here as this is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for Stack Overflow. Please also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). The [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is also a good read.

Comment: Sorry but it is too much code in the MFC application. It's hard to represent it. About the question: is it possible that the handler position (declarated in which class) can be the source of the problem?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the DoModal call and run in the debugger. Does execution reach that point? That will tell you whether the problem is with the menu or the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

A scan of your source code reveals that you are trying to handle the menu item event within the class that is going to display the dialog.

```
void CParameters::OnParam()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    CParameters dlg;
    dlg.DoModal();
}
```

I don't see anywhere else that you actually instantiate the dialog class (I may have missed it).  What you are trying is incorrect.  You cannot handle the menu item event within the same class that displays the dialog because that class (CParameters) has not been instantiated, so, it cannot respond to the menu event.  Typically, the menu event would be handled in the mainframe class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this by adding a new menu item from a simple SDI application, then trying adding that part of code in

```
CMainFrame::OnEdit
```

OnEdit method used here is obtained from the Event Handler for the new menu item and Message type being COMMAND.